# trying to copy file to remote host

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to use PowerShell to copy the latest CSV file to a share on a remote host. I have been trying to use

The name of the file is the following format: `FILENAME_2017_12_21_18_00_00.csv`.

In the PS1 file I have

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\XXXX\CSV Files\ZZZ" | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-0).Date
} | Copy-Item -Destination "V:\xxx\zzz"
```

Comment: What is your question? Something not working? What result did you expect? What was the actual result? Are you getting errors? What do they say?

Comment: Apologies. I thought I added it. The script is not working. Nothing happens. I am not even seeing output on the screen powershell. The transfer never happens. Trying to figure out if  syntax is correct.

Comment: Should be correct AFAICS. Try inspecting the pipeline step by step. Start with just the `Get-ChildItem` and see what output that gives you. Then add back the other pipeline steps one at a time and see where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your filter is doing what you want. It's giving you all of the files before today. Where I think you were intending to retrieve the files from just today (`-gt`). Also the `AddDays(-0)` doesn't do anything.

But more easily you could just `sort` on LastWriteTime and then `select` just the latest.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\XXXX\CSV Files\ZZZ" |
     Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
     Select-Object -Last 1 |
     Copy-Item -Destination "V:\xxx\zzz"
```

Comment: ahh thank you. That's much better. Now to get task scheduler to run it. Runs great from the powershell prompt but not if I double click on it, or use it from task scheduler.

Comment: I would guess folder permissions. Is your PowerShell window elevated when it works? Do only Administrators have read on `D:` or write on `V:`?

Comment: thank you. Yeah the user running the job has full control over both directories. The server is a windows 2008 R2 standard. I am wondering if that maybe has anything to do with it. Also running on the task scheduler machine, powershell version on Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1